# How to create Intent from Background Thread in FOR Loop

Tags: android, android-intent, background-thread

```
for(i=0;i<arrayLength;i++) {
                    final int j=i;
                    LinearLayout childLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                    childLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    childLinearLayout.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT                               
                    );
                    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
                    childLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    childLinearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mainColor);
                    childLinearLayout.setBaselineAligned(false);
                    childLinearLayout.setWeightSum(100);
                    parentLayout.addView(childLinearLayout);

                    TextView companyName= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            0,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
                    companyName.setLayoutParams(param1);
                    companyName.setTextSize(20);
                    companyName.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 0);
                    companyName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor));
                    companyName.setText(quotesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("company"));
                    childLinearLayout.addView(companyName);

                    TextView companyFare= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            0,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20);
                    companyFare.setLayoutParams(param2);
                    companyFare.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
                    companyFare.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor));
                    companyFare.setTextSize(20);
                    companyFare.setText(quotesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("company_fare_amount"));
                    childLinearLayout.addView(companyFare);

                    Button acceptBtn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                    acceptBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, 50));
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            0,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 30);
                    acceptBtn.setLayoutParams(param3);
                    acceptBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5);
                    acceptBtn.setId(Integer.parseInt(quotesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("company_request_id")));
                    acceptBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a15);
                    childLinearLayout.addView(acceptBtn);

                    acceptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(Quote.this, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(quotesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("company_request_id"))), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            Intent intent = new Intent(Quote.this,ConfirmFare.class);
                            try {
                                intent.putExtra("company_request_id", quotesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("company_request_id"));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }
                      });
                }
```

I am new to android development. This is my code and i am not able to move to another activity. I am creating the Intent object from Background thread's function inside the for loop. How to call the Intent from this area.This for loop is inside the onPostExecute() function. Is it right to add the view to UI from this method of background Class.

Logcat File:-

```
    04-18 18:17:15.427: V/Provider/Settings(15346): invalidate [system]: current 251 != cached 0
04-18 18:17:15.438: V/Provider/Settings(15346): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
04-18 18:17:15.448: D/skia(15346): Flag is not 10
04-18 18:17:15.626: V/InputMethodManager(15346): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810500
04-18 18:17:15.627: V/InputMethodManager(15346): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41c29030 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1080,1920} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41c2c1a0 controlFlags=#104
04-18 18:17:15.629: V/InputMethodManager(15346): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41c15d38 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #2179}
04-18 18:17:15.689: D/OpenGLRenderer(15346): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-18 18:17:16.063: D/OpenGLRenderer(15346): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-18 18:17:16.138: D/dalvikvm(15346): threadid=15: interp stack at 0x5e3fc000
04-18 18:17:16.139: D/jdwp(15346): sendRequest : Len=0x1D
04-18 18:17:16.141: D/jdwp(15346): processIncoming
04-18 18:17:16.141: D/jdwp(15346): handlePacket : cmd=0x9, cmdSet=0x9, len=0x13, id=0x59E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-18 18:17:16.143: D/jdwp(15346): processIncoming
04-18 18:17:16.143: D/jdwp(15346): handlePacket : cmd=0x5, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x59F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-18 18:17:16.144: D/jdwp(15346): processIncoming
04-18 18:17:16.144: D/jdwp(15346): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0x9, len=0x13, id=0x5A0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-18 18:17:16.145: D/jdwp(15346): processIncoming
04-18 18:17:16.145: D/jdwp(15346): handlePacket : cmd=0x2, cmdSet=0x9, len=0x1B, id=0x5A1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x10
04-18 18:17:16.147: D/jdwp(15346): processIncoming
04-18 18:17:16.148: D/jdwp(15346): handlePacket : cmd=0x4, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x5A2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-18 18:17:16.148: D/jdwp(15346):     --> RUNNING, Not SUSPENDED
04-18 18:17:16.149: D/jdwp(15346): processIncoming
04-18 18:17:16.149: D/jdwp(15346): handlePacket : cmd=0x4, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x5A3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
04-18 18:17:16.149: D/jdwp(15346):     --> RUNNING, Not SUSPENDED
```

Comment: Don't do anything UI-related on background threads.

Comment: This for loop is inside the onPostExecute() function. Is it right to add the view to UI from this method of background Class.

Comment: you might be overriding the same button time and again

Comment: @Saqib Toast is showing different id when click on different button.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: that's not an error. post the complete log in your question.

Comment: @njzk2 i have add the logcat in question. I am not able to move to the ConfirmFare View.